# ajax, jquery, and filtering drop downs

Tags: jquery

So i have these two jquery functions which pass my XHR service a key to filter the results of my list (not shown).  I'm new to jquery(and web dev in general).  These two functions are %90 the same (except for the id tags).  How could I re-write this to be more DRY-like?

```
  $('#id_group').change(function() {
    var option = $(this).val();
    $.get('jobs/update/', {group:option}, function(data) {
      $('#jobs').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });

  $('#id_location').change(function() {
    var option = $(this).val();
    $.get('jobs/update/', {location:option}, function(data) {
      $('#jobs').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing custom data to jQuery you can make use of the event object
(documented here http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)
and have one generic function to do both tasks.

```
 function doGet(e) {
    var option = $(e.target).val();
    $.get('jobs/update/',e.data, function(data) {
      $('#jobs').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });

 $('#id_group').change( {group:option}, doGet);

 $('#id_location').change({location:option}, doGet);
```

Comment: enjoy.  It is shocking how many people don't bother to learn about and use the eventObject.  Quite useful that fellow.

Answer (score 1):

If using classes is not an option, you can reference a defined function like this:

```
$('#id_group').change(function() {
    // Pass the element id to the defined function
    get_jobs( $( this ).attr( 'id' ) );
}
$('#id_location').change(function() {
    // Pass the element id to the defined function
    get_jobs( $( this ).attr( 'id' ) );
}

function get_jobs( id ) {
    var option = $( '#' + id ).val();
    $.get('jobs/update/', {location:option}, function(data) {
      $('#jobs').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not correct -- one case uses `{location:option}` and the other `{group:option}`.  You have the same parameter for both calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the same event handler for both and then just alter the backend slightly.

```
$(".get_selects").change(function () {
    var option = $(this).val();
    var type = $(this).attr("id");
    $.get('jobs/update/', {type: type, value: option}, function (data) {
        $('#jobs').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

I've changed the HTML a bit so check out the
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uVahr/